# webpack-dev-server: ERROR in missing ) after argument list @ multi main

Tags: ubuntu, reactjs, ecmascript-6, vagrant, webpack

running `npm start` yields the following error:

```
root@precise64:/vagrant/es6-react-setup# npm start

> es6-react-setup@1.0.0 start /vagrant/es6-react-setup
> webpack-dev-server

 http://localhost:3000/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from /vagrant/es6-react-setup
Hash: 34234gagawsdf3434
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 1042ms
   Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  239 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} index.js (main) 221 kB [rendered]
    [0] multi main 40 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
    [1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 3.97 kB {0} [built]
    [2] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/url.js 22.3 kB {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/~/punycode/punycode.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]
    [4] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/~/querystring/index.js 127 bytes {0} [built]
    [6] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/~/querystring/decode.js 2.4 kB {0} [built]
    [7] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/~/querystring/encode.js 2.09 kB {0} [built]
    [8] (webpack)-dev-server/~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
    [9] (webpack)-dev-server/~/strip-ansi/~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
   [10] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {0} [built]
   [11] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js 244 bytes {0} [built]
   [12] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport-list.js 613 bytes {0} [built]
   [13] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/websocket.js 2.71 kB {0} [built]
   [14] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {0} [built]
   [15] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/event.js 2 kB {0} [built]
   [16] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/random.js 746 bytes {0} [built]
   [17] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser-crypto.js 438 bytes {0} [built]
   [18] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/url.js 975 bytes {0} [built]
   [19] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/url-parse/index.js 9.9 kB {0} [built]
   [20] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/url-parse/~/requires-port/index.js 753 bytes {0} [built]
   [21] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/url-parse/lolcation.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [22] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/url-parse/~/querystringify/index.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
   [23] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/debug/browser.js 3.76 kB {0} [built]
   [24] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/debug/debug.js 4.1 kB {0} [built]
   [25] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/debug/~/ms/index.js 2.33 kB {0} [built]
   [26] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/inherits/inherits_browser.js 672 bytes {0} [built]
   [27] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js 1.27 kB {0} [built]
   [28] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
   [29] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/websocket.js 172 bytes {0} [built]
   [30] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-streaming.js 1.25 kB {0} [built]
   [31] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/ajax-based.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
   [32] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/sender-receiver.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
   [33] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/buffered-sender.js 2.3 kB {0} [built]
   [34] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/polling.js 1.32 kB {0} [built]
   [35] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/xhr.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [36] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-cors.js 343 bytes {0} [built]
   [37] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/abstract-xhr.js 4.8 kB {0} [built]
   [38] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-local.js 352 bytes {0} [built]
   [39] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser.js 560 bytes {0} [built]
   [40] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-streaming.js 984 bytes {0} [built]
   [41] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xdr.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
   [42] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/eventsource.js 766 bytes {0} [built]
   [43] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/eventsource.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [44] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/eventsource.js 37 bytes {0} [built]
   [45] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/iframe-wrap.js 981 bytes {0} [built]
   [46] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/iframe.js 3.83 kB {0} [built]
   [47] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/~/json3/lib/json3.js 43.3 kB {0} [built]
   [48] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 43 bytes {0} [built]
   [49] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/version.js 26 bytes {0} [built]
   [50] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/iframe.js 5.06 kB {0} [built]
   [51] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/object.js 532 bytes {0} [built]
   [52] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/htmlfile.js 710 bytes {0} [built]
   [53] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/htmlfile.js 2.2 kB {0} [built]
   [54] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-polling.js 894 bytes {0} [built]
   [55] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-polling.js 712 bytes {0} [built]
   [56] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/jsonp-polling.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
   [57] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/jsonp.js 5.57 kB {0} [built]
   [58] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/jsonp.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
   [59] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/main.js 11.9 kB {0} [built]
   [60] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/shims.js 18.2 kB {0} [built]
   [61] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/escape.js 2.31 kB {0} [built]
   [62] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/transport.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
   [63] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/log.js 450 bytes {0} [built]
   [64] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/event/event.js 477 bytes {0} [built]
   [65] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/location.js 177 bytes {0} [built]
   [66] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/event/close.js 295 bytes {0} [built]
   [67] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/event/trans-message.js 292 bytes {0} [built]
   [68] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/info-receiver.js 2.22 kB {0} [built]
   [69] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-fake.js 456 bytes {0} [built]
   [70] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
   [71] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe-receiver.js 791 bytes {0} [built]
   [72] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/info-ajax.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
   [73] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/iframe-bootstrap.js 2.9 kB {0} [built]
   [74] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/facade.js 723 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in missing ) after argument list
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Accessing my vagrant VM running supposedly on localhost:3000 is inaccessible as well. I wish there was more information as to where things went wrong. But here's my files for inspection:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "es6-react-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {    
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

}

I can't for the love of god figure out why this is so difficult to get up and running with node, es6.

Comment: Can you also post your `main.js`? Are you sure it's not a syntax error there? I tested your setup locally, works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you add [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) as a preloader via [`eslint-loader`](https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader) to catch simple errors like these:

```
{
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It does seem the error details might be a bit terse on the command line, but the development server should still be accessible unless you introduced a programmer error into the compilation, which doesn't seem to be the case. You should be able to access the server and see detailed messages in the web console, so you might want to check which address and  port the server is actually listening to.